# SQL insert for multi select list

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel

I have implemented [bootstrap multi select list](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) in Laravel and I have a query to insert selected items into database but my query inserts only item which has lowest `id` number. So if I select employees with id numbers `2` `3` `4`, id `2` will always be inserted and the rest is ignored.

Just to imagine what my web app is going to do: I have a car repair and every repair has its own `id`. When creating new repair, I create repair instance first, then I get it's `id` and I insert it into table `repair_employees` with columns like this: "worker_id" "repair_id".

So let's say I have new repair with `id = 87`. 
I select workers from the multi selection list with id: `2`, `3`, `4`.

So with proper sql insertion, table would look like this:

```
"repair_id" , "worker_id"
    "87"    ,     "2"
    "87"    ,     "3"
    "87"    ,     "4"
```

Here is my code for insertion:

```
public function addRepairWorker(Request $request , Vehicle $vehicle, $idcko){

        $workers_needed = null;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $idcko) {

            Log::info('Creating new repair worker instance.');

            $workers_needed = new Repair_worker();
            $workers_needed->repair_id = $idcko;
            $workers_needed->worker_id = $request->worker_id;

            DB::insert('insert into repair_worker (repair_id, worker_id) values (?, ?)',
                    [$workers_needed->repair_id, $workers_needed->worker_id]);

            Log::info('Repair created.');
            flash('Repair successfully added.', 'success');
        });
    }
```

And here (if needed) is my view (form.blade.php) for the multi selection list:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="worker_id">
        @foreach($workers as $worker)
           <option value="{{ $worker->id }}" 
                        @if(isset($repair_worker) && 
                        ($worker->id == $worker_id)) 
                        selected @endif)>
                        {{ $worker->name }} {{$worker->surname}}
           </option>
         @endforeach
</select>
```

What do I need to change to insert all "workers" ?

**EDIT:**

Here is function in my controller, where do I have to have a loop to get all array values? It's a bit confusing which part should loop to get it done.

```
public function addRepair(Request $request, Customer $customer, Vehicle $vehicle)
{
    $workers = DB::select(DB::raw('select workers.id as id, workers.name as name, workers.surname as surname from workers order by name'));

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'worker_id' => 'required'
                //'part_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $this->repairsService->createRepair($request, $vehicle);

        foreach ($workers_id as $id){
            $this->repairsService->addRepairWorker($request, $vehicle); //this function does the insert into database
        }

        return redirect()->route('Customers:detailVehicle', ['customer' => $customer, 'vehicle' => $vehicle]);
    }


    return view('repairs.form', ['repair' => null, 'workers' => $workers]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, with your select in your HTML, you need to adjust the name (note the square brackets). This will create an input value on your request as an array. If you do not do this, you will only have a single value, as it will overwrite all the previous values.

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="worker_id[]">
```

In your controller, you will need to loop through *$worker_id* array and do the insert for each value.

Also, just do:

```
$workers_needed->save();
```

instead of your insert statement, as you are defeating the purpose of having the models in the first place.